# Can i Un-call a function in Common Lisp

Tags: function, emacs, common-lisp

I'm learning `defclass` and `defmethod` and `defgeneric`, so I made a `defclass` called `savings-account` with a member `balance`.

I created a `defun` (shown below) to begin to alter the value of balance, but it's not finished.

```
(defun balance (account)
  (slot-value account 'balance))
```

Then I decided to go with a `defgeneric` (below) instead.

```
(defgeneric balance (account))
```

But when I ran the `defgeneric` I got this error:

> BALANCE already names an ordinary function or a macro.

Is there a way to un-call or undeclare balance easily so I don't have to restart my Emacs session?

Comment: Both of your code snippets use `defun`, not `defgeneric`.

Comment: @Chris....Sorry 'bout that =) I made the appropriate edits..any advice for me on this question my good man?

Comment: As an aside, you typically wouldn't do `(defun balance (account) (slot-value account 'balance)`;  you'd just define a `balance` method as a reader (or accessor):  `(defclass account ... (balance ... :reader balance ...))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any self-respecting Lisp will offer you an error *restart* to change the definition.

Here SLIME and Clozure CL:

```
The function BALANCE is defined as something other than a generic function.
   [Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Try to remove any global non-generic function or macro definition.
 1: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 2: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 3: [ABORT-BREAK] Reset this thread
 4: [ABORT] Kill this thread
```

Just select the `CONTINUE` restart by either typing 0 in that buffer or by selecting the respective line and pressing <kbd>return</kbd>.

Additionally to Xach's answer, using *SLIME* you can just move the text cursor on the function name and type <kbd>c-c c-u</kbd>, which calls `SLIME-UNDEFINE-FUNCTION`.

Comment: @Thank you very much sir,  I chose your answer  because it was the quickest way to get it done....A very nice day to you=).

Answer (score 6):

You can remove a function definition (created either with defun or defgeneric) with [fmakunbound](http://l1sp.org/cl/fmakunbound).